# how-to have multiple nodes with the same name with each interacting separately with environment

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

my  problem is that every time a new note is spawned it changes the name of the previous one so I can't remove it or changes it's action how can I fix this problem my goal is to touch each dot anywhere on the screen and it will be removed. however currently it only works with  1 dot  until  the next Dot is  spawned but i can only think of one way fixing this writing  a separate note for every 5 dots in a row however this is more of a copy and paste code then anything else and I would rather avoid this

. [image]

```
  var enemy1 = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy2 = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy3 = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy4 = SKSpriteNode()
let wate = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)

func dot (){


    let SK = SKAction.runBlock{
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock{self.spawnBlueDot()},
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])))

    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock{self.spawnBluelop()},
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])))

    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock{self.spawnGrennDot()},
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])))

    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock{self.spawnGrennlop()},
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])))


    }



 runAction(SKAction.sequence([wate,SK]))






}



func spawnBlueDot() {
    // 2
    enemy1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Oval 2@1,7x")
    // 3
    enemy1.name = "enemy1"
    // 4
    enemy1.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2 - 400, y: frame.size.height)
    // 5
    addChild(enemy1)
    scor += 1
    enemy1.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(-100, duration: 4))
    label?.text = "\(scor)"




}

func spawnBluelop() {
    // 2
    enemy2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "2@1,7xj")
    // 3
    enemy2.name = "enemy2"
    // 4
    enemy2.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2 - 100, y: frame.size.height / -900)
    // 5
    addChild(enemy2)

    enemy2.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(2000, duration: 4))



}

func spawnGrennDot() {
    // 2
    enemy3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Oval 3@1,7x")
    // 3
    enemy3.name = "enemy3"
    // 4
    enemy3.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2 + 400, y: frame.size.height)
    // 5
    addChild(enemy3)

    enemy3.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(-100, duration: 4))



}



func spawnGrennlop() {
    // 2
    enemy4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "3@vjhv")
    // 3
    enemy4.name = "enemy4"
    // 4
    enemy4.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2 + 100 , y: frame.size.height / -900)
    // 5
    addChild(enemy4)

    enemy4.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(2000, duration: 4))



 }
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    dot()

}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


  for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if pause!.containsPoint(location){
            print("help")


            enemy2.removeAllActions()
            enemy3.removeAllActions()
            enemy3.removeAllActions()
            enemy4.removeAllActions()

            pause?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ac,ac1]))


        }


    }




    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if enemy1.containsPoint(location){
            print("help")


            enemy1.removeFromParent()


        }
    }







    }
```

Comment: Try to be more descriptive... "Don't react" on what actually?

Comment: Sorry for this  I have edited  my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)`

instead of

`if enemy1.containsPoint(location)`

This will return an SKNode which you can then remove etc without having to check for each enemy individually.